# What's the difference between the Old and New GIL (before/after Python 3.2) if you set Check Interval to 100,000?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I'm trying to find differences between the Old and New GIL, using Python 2.6.4 and Python 3.2, based on [David Beazley's talk](https://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf). I ran the threaded codes below.

```
import time
import threading
import dis

def f(a, N):
    for i in range(N):
        a[i%3]+= i

def main():
    a1= [1, 2, 3]
    a2= [4, 5, 6]
    m= 1000*1000
    N= 50

    for i in range(5, N + 1, 5):        
        t1= threading.Thread(target=f, args=(a1, i * m))
        t2= threading.Thread(target=f, args=(a2, i * m))

        start_time = time.time()

        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()

        end_time = time.time()
        print(2 * i * m, end_time - start_time)

main()
```

And got some results as in the graphs below. (The sequential code mentioned the the graphs are just like the threaded code above but its one-threaded, so I don't include it here).

[Graphs of Python 2.6.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sdpS.png)

[Graphs of Python 3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfne6.png)

When you run sys.setcheckinterval(100000) on Python 2, the check interval is changed from the default value of 100 to 100,000. With that change, the performance of the threaded code on multi-core CPU on 2.6.4 is better. In fact it is **no different** from running on 3.2.

If that is the case, why is the new GIL in 3.2 better? What's *really* different about it?

Thank you.

Comment: The graphs say nothing without your code.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm sorry for that. I've included the code!

Answer (score 2):

### Why new GIL is better

The new GIL was designed to overcome the issue of starvation of IO-bound threads by the CPU-bound threads. Old GIL tends to favor CPU-bound threads over IO-bound on multi-core environment by allowing the CPU-bound threads to acquire the GIL consecutively. In the new GIL, one thread can't execute in a consecutive fashion even if it happens to acquire the GIL(it would have to release it eventually). A thread would not be able to run its bytecode until it waits for a certain duration(which in-turn would let the other thread grab the GIL).

In a nutshell, if you want to see if the new GIL is better than the old one: use IO-bound threads. You would find the responsiveness has gone up.

Typically Python applications perform IO-bound tasks. If you want to run CPU-bound code, go for running a separate thread via a C-extension(you need to release the GIL and reacquire it once done with C code).

### Regarding the performance boost when interval is increased from 100 to 100000 in old GIL

As per my analysis, the thread would release the old GIL after every 100 ticks which means there would be a switch from user space to kernel space after every 100 ticks and it would continue till the thread finishes its time-slice allocated by the OS scheduler. When you increase the tick to 100000, the thread would not release the GIL(hence no user to kernel switch) rather it would utilize the CPU thoroughly(during its time-slice) and hence you might find a performance boost since the other thread is also CPU-bound(it would also utilize the CPU fully over its time-slice).

But if the other thread happens to be an IO-bound thread, it would suffer and its responsiveness would go down.